# Compiled dynamic template can't access ng-controller functions

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

**dynamicTemplateItem.js**:

```
angular.module('mod1')
    .directive('dynamicTemplateItem', ['$rootScope', '$compile', '$parse', '$http',
      function ($rootScope, $compile, $parse, $http) {

        var linker = function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

          var templateUrl = $rootScope.dynTemplate[$attrs.type];
          // it will be something like "views/templates/template.html"
          if (templateUrl) {
            $http.get(templateUrl).then(function (response) {
              $compile($element.html(response.data).contents())($scope);
            }, function (e) {
              console.error(e);
            });
          }
        };

        return {
          restrict: "E",
          link: linker,
          scope: {
            type: '='
          }
        };

      }]);
```

**views/main html**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-cloak class="container">
      <dynamic-template-item type="login"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**views/templates/template.html**:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller1">
 <div> ctrl1 </div>

 <div ng-controller="Controller2">
    <div> ctrl2 </div>
    <select ng-change="switch()" ng-options="test.name for test in tests.availableTests track by test.id" 
                 ng-model="tests.selectedTest"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller2.js**:

```
angular.module("mod1").controller("Controller2", ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', "$state"
  function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $state) {

    // ...
    $scope.switch = function () {
      // ...
    };

  }]);
```

The problem is that `$scope.switch` function is not accessed and also any other function in `Controller2`.

What am I doing wrong?

Is was used to work before introducing dynamic templating with the `dynamicTemplateItem` directive, so before dividing `main html` and `template.html`, when I was using `templateUrl: views/main.html` in directive.

My `angularjs` version is `1.7`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are declaring the directive with an isolated scope:

```
scope: {
    type: '='
}
```

Since you don't seem to require it as you are retrieving the `type` from the attributed, you should remove the scope from de declaration and your directive should be able to access the parent scope.

```
return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: linker
};
```